# How to uncomment source code in C++?

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, ide, comments

How to uncomment many lines of source at once? In particular, this comment symbol - #

I have: Visual studio, Netbeans, DevCpp

I have this source code:

```
# /**
#  * RC4.java - Implementace algoritmu proudove sifry RC4
#  *
#  * Na zaklade vzorove implementace Arcfour algoritmu Kalle Kaukonena (1997) v
# jazyce C
#  * pro potreby vyuky na CVUT FEL prepsal do jayzka Java a upravil Lukas
# Privoznik (2008).
#  */
# package rc4;
#
# import java.io.*;
#
#
# /*
#  * Kontext S sifrovaciho algoritmu RC4
#  */
# class RC4Context {
#
#     int x;
#     int y;
#     char state[];
#
#     RC4Context() {
#         state = new char[256];
#     }
# }
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case you could use column selection.

In Visual Studio: Try holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag your mouse to form a rectangle around the first column to select all "#" occurrences and then just press delete.

In Netbeans column selection should work with <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.